# Tab independent variable ikn .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't seem to find an answer... maybe I'm not searching with the correct term...

Anyway, here is my problem. I am working on a asp.NET webform project with C# as code behind language. I created a flag, a simple boolean variable, that I used to do some server side validation. This variable is stored in session, since it has to be accessible from static WebMethods. However, if the user has the website opens in two (or more) tabs at the same time, the variable will be "shared" by all tabs.

Is it possible to have variables that are "independent" and that could also be accessible by WebMethods? I was thinking of setting the value in a hidden input, but I don't like this as the user could easily change the value using Firebox or any developper tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing it on the client is probably the best bet. If you really don't want users to be able to read it or mess with it, then associate it with a randomly generated token that would be in a hidden input element on the page. (A sufficiently randomized token would be tamper-proof because users would be very unlikely to be able to guess a valid value) The flag can then be encrypted and put in a cookie marked as http-only or stored on the server along with the associated page token.

But to answer the question: no, I don't think there is a way to distinguish between users' tabs just on the server.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do as you suggest.